# Python Tkinter and multi threading network client

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, sockets, networking, tkinter

Im working on a project for my networking class, the professor designed a game which interacts with a client through sockets by sending the user data and having the client send bytes back. I've been picked to do the client in python, i chose tkinter as my GUI for the client and its been good so far but for the cilent to keep receiving messages from the server threads are needed to run the GUI and receive from the socket continuously.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.simpledialog
from sys import exit
from struct import *
from socket import *
from threading import Thread
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst

skt = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
skt.connect(("hostname.com", 5190))
msg = skt.recv(1024)

userEntry = object

def start_func():

def create_func():
    name = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring('askstring', 'Enter Name')     
    flag = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring('askstring', 'Enter Flag')
    attack = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring('askstring', 'Enter Attack')
    defense = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring('askstring', 'Enter Defense')
    regen = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring('askstring', 'Enter Regeneration')
    Health = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring('askstring', 'Enter Health')
    Gold = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring('askstring', 'Enter Gold')
    Current_room = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring('askstring', 'Current Room')
    Description_len = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring('askstring', 'Enter descrition length')
    Description = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring('askstring', 'Enter description')

def change_func():

def fight_func():

def pvp_func():

def loot_func():

def leave_func():

def submit_value():

class TestClient(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        global userEntry
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        for n in range(3):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(n, weight=1)

        for n in range(8):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(n, weight=1)

        t1 = tkst.ScrolledText(self,wrap = WORD, width=80)
        t1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=8)
        t1.insert(INSERT,(skt.recv(500).decode("utf-8")))

        la1 = Label(self, text="Value entry:")
        la1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        userEntry = StringVar()
        global e1
        e1 = Entry(self, width=40, textvariable=userEntry)
        e1.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=6)

        e2 = Button(self, text="Enter", command=submit_value)
        e1.delete(0, END)
        e2.grid(row=1, column=5, columnspan=10)


        b1 = Button(self, text="Start", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=start_func)
        b1.grid(row=2, column=0)

        b0 = Button(self, text="Create Character", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=create_func)
        b0.grid(row=2, column=1)

        b2 = Button(self, text="Change Room", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=change_func)
        b2.grid(row=2, column=3)

        b3 = Button(self, text="FIGHT", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=fight_func)
        b3.grid(row=2, column=4)

        b4 = Button(self, text="PvP FIGHT", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=pvp_func)
        b4.grid(row=2, column=5)

        b5 = Button(self, text="Loot", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=loot_func)
        b5.grid(row=2, column=6)

        b6 = Button(self, text="Leave", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=leave_func)
        b6.grid(row=2, column=7)


root = Tk()
tw = TestClient(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This is my client right now, the button functons do not do anything at the moment as im still figuring out how to encode the messages into binary, what I am having the most trouble with right now is threading. I have not used threading that much in my time in college and it was lightly covered in the python class I took.

I tried to search for threading in tkinter but everything I found was quite a different design than my client and i wasn't able to adapt it to mine, so some help adding threading to this client that lets the GUI text widget continuously receive data from the server it would be appriciated.

Comment: A couple things:
 First, you don't need to change your message to binary if you're sending messages of text. Second, the way that you would use threading is by having a thread whose sole function is to receive messages and a `Queue` that basically relays that info back to the GUI thread.

Comment: I believe the server is expecting binary but I have that figured out ill look into queues thanks.